# Invalid type argument of '->' (Dynamic allocated vector of structs) in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc, typedef

I'm aware of using `vector[i].member` when accessing a local struct vector member. But I'm now studying dynamic allocation, and as far as I've read, I need to use `->` to access a member when the struct `vector` is dynamic.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Struct that stores a person's number and first name. 
typedef struct person{
    int number;
    char* first_name;
} Person;

int main(){

    int List_size; //Stores the size of the list. 
    scanf("%d", &List_size);

    Person* list= (Person*) malloc(List_size * sizeof(Person));     //Allocate a vector of persons struct in a variable list. 

    for(int i = 0; i < List_size; i++){       //Fills each person of list   
        scanf("%d", &(list[i]->number)); 
        (list[i]->first_name) = (char*) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s",(list[i]->first_name));    
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < List_size; i++){       //Prints each person of list
        printf("%d is list[%d].number, and ", (list[i]->number), i);
        printf("%s is list[%d].name\n", (list[i]->first_name), i);
        printf("---------------\n");
    }
}
```

The compiler says

> error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'Person')

However, when i use `list[i].member` instead of `list[i]->member`, the program works perfectly fine. I'm confused whether I'll need to use `->`. I wanted the struct vector to not use the stack memory, but the heap instead.

Comment: `list` is of type `Person *`. `list[i]` is of type `Person` so you have to use `.` instead of `->`.

Comment: Yeah, I know it will work if I use '.', but i still don't know why, since i used malloc on the vector. I wanted the program to be dynamic, but it seems it's still static

Comment: It is located on the heap.

Comment: But then, when will i use '->'? I coded it as an attempt to use '->' and I know they need to be used when accessing dynamic structs

Comment: It has nothing to do with it. `a->b` is just short for `(*a).b`. It only depends on the type of `a`, if it is a pointer to a struct or a struct. `a[i].b` is the same as `(*(a+i)).b` or `(a+i)->b`.

Comment: Person is not a pointer, it's a struct. It doesn't matter how you allocated the memory for it, what matters is the type. For a Person, use ., for a Person*, use ->

Comment: Aside: Coding in a width like 99 would prevent buffer overflow. `scanf("%99s",(list[i]->first_name));`

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'll search for a problem where I'll be forced to use ->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access a member of struct directly, you need to use `.`. To access with a pointer, you need to use `->`. In your code, `list` is a struct pointer but `list[i]` is a struct. That's why you cannot access via `->`.